# How to send Json Data along with Uploaded file in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have an react js application.I am going to upload file from react js to node js using multer as multipart-formdata.It works fine as per our requirement.My question is how to send below json data along with uploaded file.

JSONData :-

```
{"UserId":3,"FirstName":"Anees","LastName":"Ahmed","EmailId":"anees.kharind@khindia.com","MobileNo":"9789684776","DivisionId":3,"UserName":"anees","Password":"anees@123","ConfirmPassword":"","RoleId":9,"UpdateUserName":"","file":{},"Details":[{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":9,"Menu":"LGD","SubMenu":"Order Outstanding","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":1,"MenuId":11,"Menu":"GLD","SubMenu":"Current Order Status","ViewAccess":true,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":19,"Menu":"LGD","SubMenu":"HR Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":20,"Menu":"LGD","SubMenu":"HR Attrition","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":21,"Menu":"LGD","SubMenu":"Shipment Tracking","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":23,"Menu":"LGD","SubMenu":"D & D Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":2,"MenuId":27,"Menu":"GLD","SubMenu":"Leather Stock Overview","ViewAccess":true,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":3,"MenuId":28,"Menu":"GLD","SubMenu":"Leather PO Pending Details","ViewAccess":true,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":12,"MenuId":29,"Menu":"GLD","SubMenu":"HR Overview","ViewAccess":true,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":10,"MenuId":30,"Menu":"GLD","SubMenu":"D & D Production detail","ViewAccess":true,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":31,"Menu":"HO","SubMenu":"Payment receivable details","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":43,"Menu":"HnS","SubMenu":"H & S Sales Details","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":44,"Menu":"HnS","SubMenu":"H & S Shoes Factory Order Details","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":46,"Menu":"KHRS","SubMenu":"Greenfield Sales Details","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":47,"Menu":"KHRS","SubMenu":"Stock Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":48,"Menu":"HnS","SubMenu":"Stock Details","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":49,"Menu":"KHRS","SubMenu":"Break Even Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":50,"Menu":"KHRS","SubMenu":"Camp Sales Details","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":51,"Menu":"HnS","SubMenu":"Order Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":52,"Menu":"FWD","SubMenu":"Order Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":11,"MenuId":53,"Menu":"GLD","SubMenu":"Attendance Overview","ViewAccess":true,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":54,"Menu":"FWD","SubMenu":"HR Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":55,"Menu":"LGD","SubMenu":"Order In Value Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":56,"Menu":"FWD","SubMenu":"Leather Stock Details","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null},{"UserAccessId":null,"MenuId":58,"Menu":"tt","SubMenu":"HR Overview","ViewAccess":false,"ZohoParameter":null,"Remarks":null}]}
```

fileupload code :-

```
 const data = new FormData()
 data.append('UserId', this.state.UserId) 
 data.append('FirstName', this.state.FirstName) 
 data.append('LastName', this.state.LastName) 
 data.append('MobileNo', this.state.MobileNo) 
 data.append('DivisionId', this.state.DivisionId) 
 data.append('UserName', this.state.UserName) 
 data.append('Password', this.state.Password) 
 data.append('RoleId', this.state.RoleId) 
 data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile) 
 data.append('Details', this.state.GridState) 
 console.log(data); // Why no data is showing in console ??

 axios.post(ConfigItem[0].APIPath+'Users/', data)

  .then(res => {

      this.props.history.push('/UserList')

  })  





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply append the JSON to your data object as well:
`data.append('myJson', myJson)`

Comment: thanks for reply,I have tried above code but data is not showing in console.please check updated code

Comment: thanks for reply...Noted well but how can I console in server side (node js) after sending data to server for example console.log(req).

Comment: @MohammedIsmail actually this is a whole another question but you should be able to console it with `req.body`

Comment: actually my requirement is sending this json data to server and update in sql table and then finally upload the file in server with the help of above json data

Answer (score 0):

You cannot console.log Form data

If you want to console.log you can do like this

```
for (let entry of data.entries()) {
    console.log('Key', entry[0]);
    console.log('Value', entry[1]); 
}
```