# How to pass a file data in JSON payload to restful API

Tags: reactjs, post

How can we pass file data along with other key-value pairs in the JSON payload in ReactJs?

I have a form where one input is of file type and others are simple text type input boxes. I have to pass the file and other input values to the restful post API in the JSON format from the frontend.

Comment: I think it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710300/how-to-send-json-data-along-with-uploaded-file-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more context for this question?

A shot in the dark is you could use:

```
const ImportFromFileBodyComponent = () => {
  let fileReader;
  
  const handleFileRead = (e) => {
    const content = fileReader.result;
    console.log(content)
    // … do something with the 'content' …
  };
  
  const handleFileChosen = (file) => {
    fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = handleFileRead;
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  };
  
  return <div className='upload-expense'>
    <input
      type='file'
      id='file'
      className='input-file'
      accept='.csv'
      onChange={e => handleFileChosen(e.target.files[0])}
    />
  </div>;
};
```

This might provide you the contents of the file and you can use those in the application you desire.

Comment: I have a form where one input is of file type and others are simple text type input boxes. I have to pass the file and other input values to the restful post API in the JSON format from the frontend.

Comment: @Dharm Ah I see what you mean. You need to pass both the file and inputs down to an api call. Well this should help you: https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/ once you have the file from the input you can just merge the two objects.